# Deriving chromatic polynomials

Tags: graph-theory, polynomials, coloring

How to derive the chromatic polynomial from a Cycle? I derived the chromatic polynomial for a triangle $ K_3$ it's: $t(t-1)(t-2)$ But I don't understand how to get it for Cycles $C_n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use deletion/contraction. For any graph $G$ and any two connected vertices $x,y$,
$$ P(G) = P(G-xy) - P(G/xy), $$
where $P(H)$ is the chromatic polynomial of $H$, $G-xy$ is obtained from $G$ by removing the edge $(x,y)$, and $G/xy$ is obtained from $G$ by contracting (identifying) $x,y$.

In the case of the cycle, this implies
$$
P(C_n) = P(P_n) - P(C_{n-1}),
$$
where $P_n$ is the path on $n$ vertices (and $n-1$ edges). This shows that
$$
P(C_n) = P(P_n) - P(P_{n-1}) + P(P_{n-2}) - \cdots \pm P(P_3) \mp P(P_2).
$$
It is easy to compute $P(P_n) = t(t-1)^{n-1}$, and this gives a formula for $P(C_n)$:
$$
\begin{align*}
P(C_n) &= t[(t-1)^{n-1} - (t-1)^{n-2} + (t-1)^{n-3} - \cdots \pm (t-1)] \\ &=
(-1)^{n-1}t[(1-t)^{n-1} + \cdots + (1-t)] \\ &=
(-1)^{n-1}t(1-t)\frac{(1-t)^{n-1}-1}{-t} \\ &=
(-1)^n[(1-t)^n - (1-t)].
\end{align*}
$$